# how to set multiple element variable for CMakefile

Tags: cmake, gnu-make

I can pass defined variable for cmake like below(for example when I want to set PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH=dir1).

```
cmake -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH=dir1 ..
```

But what if I want to set multiple paths for this PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH? I tried

```
cmake -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH='dir1 dir2 dir3'
```

or should it be

```
cmake -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH='dir1:dir2:dir3' (or , instead of :)
```

But I'm not sure it's valid. (see some other error so I am not sure yet if it's correct or not.)

I saw I can also set these defines in .cmake file like set(VARIABLE,VALUE) like below.

```
set(OpenCV_CUDA_VERSION 7.5)
```

Then what's the corresponding syntax for this set(..) form when the variable has multiple elements?

Comment: The list delimiter in CMake is `;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the following syntax:

```
cmake -DLIST_VAR="one;two;three" ...
```

you can play w/ the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

foreach(v IN LISTS LIST_VAR)
    message(STATUS "${v}")
endforeach()
```